# Concatenation in $http.jsonp filltext string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

Hello i'm trying to do dynamic $http request to filltext.com server.
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <meta carset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body >
    <div class="container" ng-controller="theController">
        <div ng-repeat="person in people">
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.fname">
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.lname">


        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
    var app=angular.module('App', []);
    app.controller('theController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.getPeople=function(count){
            $http.jsonp("http://www.filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows="+count+"&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}").
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.people = data;
    })
        };

        $scope.countSelection=10;
        $scope.getPeople($scope.contSelection);

    }]);

    </script>       

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is when i'm trying to add +count+ into $http.jsonp string parametr i'm not getting data from filltext.com, but when i write rows=5 statically then it's generating data
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Seems like you have a simple typo. You have `cont` should be `count`: `$scope.getPeople($scope.countSelection);`.

Comment: You are right :D it's gonna kill me is there a way how to find this simple typos? Thank you

Comment: Use good IDE it would highlight unknown variables.

Comment: Hwhat IDE are you using i'm currently using sublime text

Comment: I use Webstorm. Download trial version, and after 30 days you will never leave it :)

Comment: Ok thank you for your insight and keen eye :)